# how to prevent brut force attack on couchdb?

Tags: security, couchdb, brute-force

I have a couchdb server open to all IP sources.
Each client make a request this way :

```
http://username:password@couchdb/database
```

How can I prevent a brut force attack ?
Is there a way to ban a source if there is an auth problem after X trials ?

Comment: Maybe with a service like `fail2ban` ?

Comment: fail2ban is only for ssh?